# Revert an invalid value in knockout without subscriptions firing

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

Is it possible to revert a value change to a view model with something other than a custom binding handler (maybe an extender) *without the subscriptions firing*?

For example, say you have a numeric field that only allows values up to 100. If someone types 101, we want the value to drop back to the previous value and most importantly *not* fire any subscriptions on the reverted value.

I'm trying to find a generic way of accomplishing this without having to write a custom binding handler that inherently would require duplication of core knockout code to handle text fields, select fields, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went down the same route that @Jalayn had suggested already, and ended up doing something similar to the issue listed in the comments on his answer. I'm still not a huge fan of this as it requires you to check at the top of the subscription to see if the value has *actually* changed, but at least it is possible.

The full solution and QUnit tests are posted here: https://github.com/gotdibbs/ko.extenders.filteredUpdate/.

The key components to making this work are an extender to "protect" the view model from unwanted changes using a computed observable, and a custom function extending subscribables to *work in place off* a normal subscription which would fire on every change regardless of if the value is actually changing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can be done with an extender, like this:

```
ko.extenders.numeric = function(target, properties) {
    var result = ko.computed({
        read: target,
        write: function(newValue) {
            var current = target();
            var valueToWrite = newValue;
            if(properties) {
                if(properties.maxNum && properties.maxNum < newValue) {
                    valueToWrite = current;
                }
                if(properties.minNum && properties.minNum > newValue) {
                    valueToWrite = current;
                }
            }

            if(valueToWrite !== current) {
                target(valueToWrite);
            } else {
                target.notifySubscribers(valueToWrite);
            }
        }
    });

    result(target());
    return result;
};
```

And this is how you use it:

```
self.number = ko.observable().extend({numeric: { minNum: 50, maxNum: 100} });
```

You can test that in the [fiddle I've created](http://jsfiddle.net/megrF/2/).

You can comment the `target.notifySubscribers(valueToWrite)` line but what will happen is that if you change that value from outside (like in an `input` element), the value will not be updated back to the previous one.

Comment: Thanks for your post. You're at the same point I am actually already. The problem is that with this solution the subscriptions are called when the value is reverted back to its previous value, that is in fact what I am trying to avoid here. I've updated my question to clarify. See a forked version of your fiddle here for the subscription calls: http://jsfiddle.net/9TkDk/

Comment: i don't understand the concept of an extender. where is the documentation for them?

Comment: @GotDibbs Have you seen https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/issues/711 ? The solution at the bottom of the page may work, I don't know, but it seems overkill...

Comment: @Jalayn That's a similar path to where I'm headed currently, thanks for the share. I'll post my workaround in a bit, but I'm still hopeful that there is a more elegant solution.